# D3 generated rectangle "click" function not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg, onclick

Inside of my d3 code, I generate a rectangle like this:

```
     svg.selectAll("g")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", 30)
        .attr("height", 30)
        .attr("class", "close-box initial-hidden")
        .attr("x", 500)
        .attr("y", 110)
        .on("click", function() {
            $('.initial-hidden').hide();
        })
        .append("text")
        .text("x")
```

I am using click events on many of my other svg elements and they are working fine, but I can't get the click event on the rectangle to work at all.  Am I missing something about SVG rectangle?

Comment: See if you can click it on a separate select. So create it like you have above, and then select and add the click. Not sure if it'll work, but give it a try

Comment: can you post the rest of your code, or possible a link to a jsfiddle?

Comment: Nothing wrong in the code...may be some other element is handeling the click event..a fiddle will be good